# Iterate over formula elements in R

Tags: r, formula

Is there a way how to iterate over formula in R?
what I need to do lets say we have a formula given as: `as.formula(hp ~ factor(gear) + qsec + am)`

What I need to do is to iterate over elements of formula So I can create 3 model (3 because we use 3 regressors - no counting dummies)

I need to create first model as `as.formula(hp ~ factor(gear))`, then second like `as.formula(hp ~ factor(gear) + qsec)` and lastly `as.formula(hp ~ factor(gear) + qsec + am)`

Can we somehow use just one regressor in one iterration, then use two and when use three?

I need to automatize this for function and "hand" approach is not good

Comment: check out the guts of `MuMIn::drege()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach here: create a string using `sprintf` and `paste` (with `collapse` option), coerce it to a formula, and then loop over the elements you want to include.

```
elements <- c("factor(gear)", "qsec", "am")

for (i in 1:length(elements)) {
    fmla <- as.formula(sprintf("hp ~ %s", paste(elements[1:i], collapse = " + ")))
    print(fmla)
    print(summary(lm(fmla, data = mtcars)))
}
```

If you need to parse the formula gave, you could do something like this before running the loop above (might need to be modified for your specific setup):

```
library(stringr)
input_fmla <- "as.formula(hp ~ factor(gear) + qsec + am)"
temp <- str_remove_all(input_fmla, "(as.formula\\([^ ]* ~ |\\)$)")
elements <- trimws(str_split(temp, pattern = "\\+")[[1]])
```

Comment: the question is whether the OP is given the formula or gets to have the elements specified separately (you can deparse and split the formula, but it's trickier)

Comment: and is there a way how to create `elements` from formula.